# How to change Windows language in Windows 7 Professional

Tags: windows-7, language-pack

How can I change the Windows language from Spanish to English in a Windows 7 Professional?

Please note that this is not Enterprise or Ultimate version. So the normal way using a [MUI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb978454.aspx) is not possible.

Comment: This question is really not a duplicate, it is the other way around. The "duplicate" does not give any useful answer while this one does.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The installation of additional languages is normally not possible - unless you upgrade to Windows 7 Ultimate or Enterprise.

However, it can be done. But it will violate your [Windows EULA](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/DisplayHelpEULAPage).

### Instructions

1. Download the [MUI (Multilingual User Interface) for your Language](http://www.froggie.sk/7lp64sp1.html). I downloaded the hu-HU package on `C:\lp.cab`. You have to change the path and language shorthand to your own
2. After the download completes, open a command line prompt as administrator and type

   ```
   DISM /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:C:\lp.cab
   bcdedit /set {current} locale hu-HU
   bcdboot %WinDir% /l hu-HU
   ```
3. Open *regedit.exe* and delete the `en-EN` key under

   > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / SYSTEM / CurrentControlSet / Control / MUI / UILanguages
4. Reboot

[Source](http://my.bergersoft.net/2010/02/26/how-to-change-default-language-on-windows-7-professional/)

Comment: This leads to blue screen bad answer

Comment: I know that this has worked in the past for others and I, could it be possible that an update has stopped this working?

Comment: Best way download english version burn it to a dvd install it, then Use your old serial number.

Comment: Working for me even with newest windows updates (2016/11)

Comment: This is not working at all. Black screen. It is a problem

Comment: Perfect! Works on a fully updated Windows 7 Pro machine as of August 2018.

Comment: oh yeah! this works!